# When we are trying to deploy serialized items using Sitecore CLI in Devops pipeline getting error

Tags: scs

We are getting the below error only when deploying in Production env but the same DevOps pipeline works fine for lower env. Any insight?

> ERROR [Sitecore Identity]
> 'http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer' claim is
> missing
>
> ERROR
> Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware -
> Authentication failed
>
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Message: Cannot find user builder
>
> Source: Sitecore.Owin.Authentication
>
> at
> Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultApplicationUserResolver.d__16.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved the issue with help of the Sitecore support team.

We have customized the below DefaultExternalUserBuilder pipeline and that caused the root cause for the Sitecore Serialization during deployment.

`<externalUserBuilder  type="Foundation.FederatedAuthentication.Services.ExternalDomainUserBuilder, Foundation.FederatedAuthentication"  patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']"  resolve="true">`